# preventing jquery from modifying on focus css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Initial css:

```
#id_etiket{
width: calc(94% + 1px);
```

I modify an element's width via jquery as shown below:

```
     function entry_delete(id){
        if('{{request.user_agent.is_mobile}}' === "False"){
        $('#id_etiket').css('width', "calc(94% + 2px)");
```

The same element's width is also modified on css side while it's focused:

```
#id_etiket:focus{
    width: calc(100% - 7px);}
```

When jquery function is triggered first it also overrides element's on focus width and it becomes  `calc(94% + 2px)` instead of `width: calc(100% - 7px)`. Is there any way of preventing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!important` in your CSS.

```js
$('#id_etiket').css('width', "calc(94% + 2px)");
```

```css
#id_etiket:focus{
    width: calc(100% - 7px) !important;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id_etiket" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: dodgerblue;" tabindex="-1">
Click to focus
</div>
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enought, the first width of div is not "calc(94% + 2px)" it is changed to it by the jquery function that I also posted, which overrides the on focus css, and nope !important not working for that.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use CSS variables instead of using `!important`. (I showed with the background to make it more understandable.)

```js
$('#id_etiket').css('--custom-bg', "red");
```

```css
#id_etiket {
  /*          var( use this variable if exist, fallback (default) value) */
  background: var(--custom-bg, blue);
}

#id_etiket:focus {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="id_etiket">
```

For your case:

```js
$('#id_etiket').css('--custom-width', "calc(94% + 2px)");
```

```css
#id_etiket {
  width: var(--custom-width, calc(94% + 1px));
}

#id_etiket:focus {
  width: calc(100% - 7px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="id_etiket">
```